# css animation in chrome not working

Tags: html, css, slider, css-animations

I can't figure out the reason of the different behavior of my slider in firefox (works fine) and chrome (act weirdly)

I've made a jsfiddle with all the rules in case it was the problem, but it fix nothing...

https://jsfiddle.net/86mmns1z/13/

as you can see, it's a slider controlled by two sets of buttons : the little white in the bottom can get you at the appropriate image, so it works in both direction, with a simple transition

but the red square on the left and right of the slider are working as an infinite slider. I'm doing that by using animation, and hiding or showing the button whether I want it to use the transition or the animation, so that it's always connected to the state of the radio button (I don't know if it's clear...)

however, it's working on firefox but not on chrome (in the jsfiddle i've set the time of the animation to 1.4s so you can clearly see what's going wrong). It seems that transition works before animation, so I've put !important to the animation but it changes nothing

the html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="slider">
        <input type="radio" name="arrow" id="left" checked>
        <label for="left" id="dotLeft" class="dot"></label>
    <label for="left" id="arrowLeft" tabindex="0"></label>
        <label for="left" id="arrowFalseRight" tabindex="0"></label>
        <input type="radio" name="arrow" id="right">
        <label for="right" id="dotRight" class="dot"></label>
        <label for="right" id="arrowRight" tabindex="0"></label>
        <label for="right" id="arrowFalseLeft" tabindex="0"></label>
        <div id="wrapper">
        </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the css :

```
/*the animation code*/
#slider #arrowFalseLeft:focus ~ #wrapper {
    animation: 1.4s slideLeft;
}
#slider #arrowFalseRight:focus ~ #wrapper {
    animation: 1.4s slideRight;
}
@keyframes slideLeft {
    0% {left: -300%;}
    100% {left: -200%;}
}
@keyframes slideRight {
    0% {left: -0%;}
    100% {left: -100%;}
}
#slider input#right:checked ~ #wrapper {
    left: -200%;
}

/*general settings*/
#slider {
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-bottom: 5%;
}
#slider #wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: -100%;
    width: 400%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-c984SeiXG-M/UK9IxFjg-cI/AAAAAAAABdA/ZG9VuKMcXps/s1600/White+Pelican+Best+Shot.jpg),
  url(http://tnregneanimal.tableau-noir.net/pages10/images/hippopotame010.jpg),
  url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-c984SeiXG-M/UK9IxFjg-cI/AAAAAAAABdA/ZG9VuKMcXps/s1600/White+Pelican+Best+Shot.jpg),
  url(http://tnregneanimal.tableau-noir.net/pages10/images/hippopotame010.jpg);
    background-size: 25%, 25%, 25%, 25%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position: 0% 0%, calc(100% / 3) 0%, calc(2 * 100% / 3) 0%, 100% 0%;
    transition: all 0.4s;
    z-index: -1;
}
#slider #arrowLeft {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5%;
    width: 2%;
    left: 40px;
    top: 45%;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#slider #arrowRight {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5%;
    width: 2%;
    right: 40px;
    top: 45%;
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#slider #arrowFalseLeft {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5%;
    width: 2%;
    left: 40px;
    top: 45%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#slider #arrowFalseRight {
    position: absolute;
    height: 5%;
    width: 2%;
    right: 40px;
    top: 45%;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background-color: red;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#slider input#left:checked ~ label#arrowLeft,
#slider input#left:checked ~ label#arrowFalseRight {
    display: none;
}
#slider input#right:checked ~ label#arrowRight,
#slider input#right:checked ~ label#arrowFalseLeft {
    display: none;
}
#slider input {
    display: none;
}
#slider .dot {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10%;
    padding-top: 1%;
    width: 1%;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.6);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
}
#slider #dotLeft {
    left: 48.5%;
}
#slider #dotRight {
    right: 48.5%;
}
#slider input:checked + .dot {
    background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

does someone know what's happening ?

Comment: nobody knows how to fix that in chrome ?